# Using Linq with a DbDataReader

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make use of the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041405/is-there-an-implementation-of-iqueryable-over-dbdatareader) to implement a query like this:

```
    public void LoadLive(DbConnection pConnection)
    {
        using (DbDataReader lReader = pConnection.ExecuteReader("..."))
        {
            mList.AddRange(from t in lReader select new MyObject { Name = t.GetString(0) });
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to compile this (with the extension method in place), I receive this error:

```
 error CS1934: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 't'.
```

Am I missing something about how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call the extension method from the answer in the linked question:

```
 mList.AddRange(from t in lReader.AsEnumerable() 
                select new MyObject { Name = t.GetString(0) });
```

Comment: This was close, but for convenience, I implemented a Select extension method that does the `AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to write your own extension method, Select, Where, etc all return an IEnumerable and the typical method signature will resemble `Func<DbDataReader, myT>`. What you are looking for is something like [Jon Skeet's sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt/1464929#1464929).

Answer (score 0):

[Compiler error `CS1934`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531202%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is produced when no standard query operators are implemented for a given datasource.

In your case (`DbDataReader`), you could specify the type of `t` as `IDataRecord`:

```
mList.AddRange(from IDataRecord t in lReader
               select new MyObject { Name = t.GetString(0) });
```